# Were there any converted children or teenagers among Jesus disciples or in the first century church?

Tags: baptism, children, conversion

Since children and teenagers (minors) conversions are not recorded in the entire New Testament, I always wondered if they were qualified candidates for Christianity.

Comment: What time period are you talking about? Only up to the end of New Testament times? Also, your last paragraph is going to be speculation. I would suggest removing it, or specifying which branch of Christianity you want an answer from.

Comment: There is a Catholic "legend" that St  Ignatius  of Antioch was the child whom the Savior took up in His arms, as described in Mark 9:35. It is also believed, and with great probability, that, with his friend Polycarp, he was among the auditors of the Apostle St. John. If we include St. Peter, Ignatius was the third Bishop of Antioch and the immediate successor of Evodius (Eusebius, Church History II.3.22).

Comment: Wouldn't children conversion in the NT be a speculation as well?

Comment: One of the gospel writers (Mark, I think (so not posting as an answer)) is said to have been a child who saw Jesus' betrayal in Gethsemane, and then wrote the gospel when he grew up.

Answer (score 3):

### Suffer the little children to come unto me, for such is the kingdom of God. (Paraphrased)

It is entirely the opposite. Unless you are converted and become as one of these little ones,  you shall in no wise enter the Kingdom of God.

> Mar 10:13-16  And they brought young children to him, that he should touch them: and his disciples rebuked those that brought them. (14)  But when Jesus saw it, he was much displeased, and said unto them, Suffer the little children to come unto me, and forbid them not: for of such is the kingdom of God. (15)  Verily I say unto you, Whosoever shall not receive the kingdom of God as a little child, he shall not enter therein. (16)  And he took them up in his arms, put his hands upon them, and blessed them.

I do realize, that you make the special case of qualifying 'teenagers' in your post, as well as children in general. I can only attribute this to some notion of accountability, which in Jewish tradition is , I believe, age 13. I do not see any support for this as a regulatory restriction, in any terms of eligibility for salvation.

There is certainly not a single mention in all of scripture that would support this idea that children would, of all souls, ever be denied by Jesus Christ; Old or New.
I will say in response to the question of some ineligibility; emphatically, no.

Comment: Mediterranean cultural context from that era is missing from this answer.  (Let's say some of our current cultural assumptions don't match the ones from that time.  Don't have my copy of Pilch's book on cultural context for that era handy.)

Comment: An 'interesting' remark. However, if you look closely, you will see that my answer does no make allowance for any demographic; by culture, or era. Even had the Q insisted upon it, I would have proposed transcendence in the terms of salvation, in any case. I do not perceive any caveats in the words "Come unto me, all..." Matt 11:28, I believe, or Rev 22 something close to there, "Whosoever will let him come, and partake of the waters of life freely; or whosoever hears the words of the gospel and believes, will be saved; Jesus himself John chapter 5:24. No. No culture, era, prevalent notion. No.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was matching in my head what I saw as a question based on current norms, and your addressing that somewhat just under the quote box.  I had an idea that elaborating on that would help match the contemporary feel to the question (in terms of cultural context) but your "timeless" approach certainly fits.  Thanks for the further explanation.